# ASP page don't recognize variables

Tags: asp.net, variables

I have defined a variable in page Test.aspx.cs, `public string TestText = "Select";`

I want to use it in the page Test.aspx,  `<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAccessories" Text="<%=TestText %>" runat="server" CommandName="Select">`

But the aspx page doesn't recognize the variable, in firefox it shows <%=TestText %>, and in IE7 it shows nothing.

Does anyone know where is wrong and how to show the variable?

Thanks

Comment: That's a _field_, not variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `<%= .. %>` expressions to set proeprties of server-side controls.
(this has nothing to do with the field)

Instead, you can set the property directly in the code-behind:

```
 lbAccessories.Text = "Hi!";
```

**EDIT**: You can use databinding syntax: (with a `#`)

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAccessories" Text="<%#TestText %>" runat="server" CommandName="Select">
```

Comment: Because LinkButton is in the gridview control, i can not assign a value to it directly.